# ¿Qué significan las "," en prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Aprendiendod prolog me he topado con programas que en las reglas usan "," para separar términos ¿Cómo se debería leer? Dejo un ejemplo.

```
fibonnacci(N,M) :- N > 1, N1 is N-1, N2 is N-2, fibonacci(N1, F1), fibonacci(N2, F2), M is F1 + F2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando en el cuerpo de la regla (es decir después del `:-`) encuentras coma, cada cosa separada por comas es una condición adicional que se debe de cumplir.

Por ejemplo en tu caso poniendo identado tu código

```
fibonnacci(N,M) :-
 N > 1,
 N1 is N-1,
 N2 is N-2,
 fibonacci(N1, F1),
 fibonacci(N2, F2),
 M is F1 + F2.
```

Para resolverlo pasará por los siguientes pasos

```
N=?, M=?
% N>1
N=2, M=?
% N1 is N-1,
N=2, M=?, N1=1
% N2 is N-2,
N=2, M=?, N1=1, N2=0
% fibonacci(N1, F1),
false no se cumple N1>1 y F1 no se puede determinar
```

a partir de esta primera tentativa seguira probando cambiar los valores de las variables que ha probado, empezando por ponerle a `N` el valor de `3`.

como tal vez podrás intuir en todo el rango de los numeros naturales positivos no va a poder cumplir todas las condiciones y `F1` no se podrá determinar.

Para que tu función realmente sirva de algo necesitas definir otra regla que te permita saber que hacer en caso de que `N<2`, de allí que se le llame condición de paro o caso base.

Ahora respecto a la parte de parámetros de la regla y a diferencia de la programación funcional, en prolog establecemos relaciones y algunas de ellas pueden ser biyectivas, es decir podemos sacar implicaciones e inferencias adicionales conforme vamos definiendo la relación.

En tu caso, por la forma en que está escrito tu código podemos inferir que N es la entrada y M es la salida, ya que si proveemos M en vez de N la secuencia de cada condición que se debe de cumplir nos traerá el problema de que tendremos que evaluarlas todas antes de siquiera poder intentar poner valores.

Te doy un ejemplo más:

```
sumaPar(Numero1,Numero2):- % sea la relacion entre Numero1 y Numero2 denominada como suma par donde
         between(1,10, Numero1), %Numero1 es un valor entre 1 y 10
         between(1,10, Numero2), %Numero2 es un valor entre 1 y 10
         Suma is Numero1+Numero2, % y sea Suma la adición de Numero1 y Numero2
         mod(Suma,2,0). % donde el residuo de dividir Suma entre dos es 0
```

En esta regla, si te fijas la relación entre ambas variables no es tan difícil de calcular, ya que tuvimos en cuenta la buena práctica de ponerle un rango de valores aceptables como parte de las primeras condiciones, de manera que podemos hacer nuestra consulta sin prolbemas con:

- sumaPar(X,2)
- sumaPar(2,X)
- sumaPar(X,Y)

usando el mismo código fuente. Escribir la misma funcionalidad en otros lenguajes nos llevaría muchísimas líneas de código y posiblemente no sería tan eficiente, este es el poder de este lenguaje.

A que viene con lo de las comas?

pues que en la cabeza de la regla, entre los paréntesis podemos poner nuestras Variables de entrada y/o salid separadas por comas, y muchos solemos llamarles parámetros.

```
hola_mundo :-
     write('hola mundo'),nl.
```

Los parametros son opcionales como puedes ver.

Cuando quieras ver como se ejecutan las condiciones paso por paso y de manera interactiva escribe en tu intérprete de prolog favorito:

```
trace.
```

y para desactivarlo usa

```
notrace.
```

Te invito a probar nuestra regla `sumaPar` con `trace` para que entiendas mejor como se evaluan los predicados en prolog.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente las comas (`,`) significan *conjunciones* lógicas. Por ejemplo,

```
c(X,Y):- p(X),q(Y).
```

puede reescribirse lógicamente como *p(X) ∧ q(Y) ⇒ c(X,Y)*. También los `;` son *disyunciones lógicas*, es decir `c(X,Y):-p(X);q(Y).` se puede reescribir como *p(X) ∨ q(Y) ⇒ c(X,Y)*.